# Can two PCs in different networks can ping each other without using a router?

Tags: networking

Suppose our organization has been assigned a class /24 subnet 216.21.5.0. Then we subnetted that and used 255.255.255.224 as our new subnet mask, so the network ranges are 216.21.5.0-216.21.5.31, 216.21.5.32-216.21.5.63, .64 -.95 and so on. Would a PC in 216.21.5.0 -216.21.5.31 be able to ping a PC in a different subnetwork eg:216.21.5.64 -216.21.5.95 without using a router?

And can this be done using VLANs?

Answer (score 3):

No and No. Moving packets between IP networks (which you created by subnetting) is done by a router.

A netmask and ipaddress determines what other addresses can be contacted directly on an interface. If you want all your machines to communicate without going through a router then use a netmask that covers the whole IP address range and skip subnetting.

Comment: VLANs partition switches, i.e. limiting the ports on which broadcast traffic is flooded or visible.  You still need a router or something that can route "in between" VLANs.  It's possible some "Layer 2 router" devices may have this feature.  It would be a feature specific to your router.

Answer (score 2):

you can even ping two hosts in a different VLAN with out a router provided both hosts should share same network ID.

This can be achieved by playing with NATIVE VLAN.